# ByteArray readFloat issue - ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, arrays

Can someone explain to me, why this happens?

```
var float:Number = 1.40;
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

trace('float: ' + float);
bytes.writeFloat( float );
bytes.position = 0;
trace('bytes.readFloat: ' + bytes.readFloat() );
```

Output from trace:

```
>> float: 1.4
>> bytes.readFloat: 1.399999976158142
```

this driving me crazy in the last hours.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ByteArray.writeFloat()` writes only 4 bytes, meaning a single precision flosting-point value gets stored. You have to call `writeDouble()` to write your float, and even then you might lose precision, although that loss won't be as drastical. This is the core limitation of floating point types.

Comment: That works, but what I cant understand is why/how a float value 1.40 cant be stored in 4 bytes.

Comment: This is easy to explain. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) is the detailed explanation. 1.40 is a binary fraction of infinite length, therefore the computer has to truncate it at some point. When your float gets displayed, it first is converted to double, and the unstored binary digits of the fraction are set to 0, so the actual value of the converted float is different.

Answer (score 2):

Will that suit you to use double here?

This should work fine:

```
var double:Number = 1.40;
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

trace('double: ' + double);
bytes.writeDouble( double );
bytes.position = 0;
trace('bytes.readDouble: ' + bytes.readDouble() );
```